# Solving Poisson probability problem using only other known probabilities

Tags: poisson-distribution

Suppose $X_t\sim Poisson(\lambda t)$. I'm looking at an exercise problem where two probability statements are given, and the exercise is to algebraically determine the value of a third probability:

$P(X_1=1)=0.36788$

$P(X_2=3)=0.18405$

$P(X_1=2)=\ ?$

I know $\lambda$ could easily be solved for algebraically if $P(X_t=0)$ is given for any $t$... but in this case, the PMF of $X_t$ can't be used to algebraically solve for $\lambda$.

The exercise says to use an algebraic approach -- not to manually try to find $\lambda$ through guesswork or Newton Raphson. So I want to ignore the fact that I could simply inspect and see that $\lambda=1$ and use that to solve the requested probability. What is the algebraic way to approach this, that would work in cases where $\lambda$ wasn't a simple value such as 1?

Comment: Because $\Pr(X_1=3)/\Pr(X_1=1)=\lambda^2/6,$ you **can** solve this algebraically for $\lambda.$  You will discover the solution is not a "simple value," but it is easily found.

Comment: Jonathan does not know $P(X_1=3)$. But of course, your idea is right.

Comment: @FPO Good catch--I overlooked the subscript "2" in the second equation.

Answer (score 7):

Since $X_t\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda t)$, $$\mathbb{P}(X_t=k)=e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\left(\lambda t\right)^k}{k!}$$
As a consequence, you can develop expressions of your values $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_2=3)$ as functions of $\lambda$. Then, you can find a couple of ways to use these 2 formulas and the numerical values you know in order to determine the value of $\lambda$.

Hint:

> Determine the formula for $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)^2$.